# Older monitor not working with HDMI to DVI cable (from ultrabook)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a Lenovo Yoga ultrabook which only has a HDMI port. I bought an HDMI to DVI cable, and it works as expected with a LG monitor in my office. As soon as I plug it in the screen is cloned.

At home I have an older Dell UltraSharp 2005fp, and for that one it does not work. When I plug the cable in "something" happens, the monitor goes from the "no signal" screen to black.
On the laptop however nothing happens. In the Windows 8 display setup I don't have another monitor, clicking "detect" does not find one either. I can manually set a second display for cloning or extending, but never get a picture on the Dell.

Connecting my media player thing with the cable to the Dell monitor works for when the player displays it's logo at a low resolution, but when it goes into 750p mode after booting the picture also goes away. Mabye that's due to HDCP though.

Any ideas? Something to do with Windows 8, or DVI versions?

Answer (score 1):

What is your firmware version ? This monitor is known for having lots of problems so check your firmware version and update before you do much further.

```
1- Turn off your screen
2- Press simultaneously the 'Menu' and '+' button of the screen.
3- While holding the 2 buttons, press now the 'Power' button.
4- Once the screen in ON, unpress the 3 buttons.
5- Just press '-' button.
```

Comment: Some reference to "is known for" [The Dell UltraSharp 2005FPW had problems obtaining/holding DVI signals at 1680x1050](http://www.anandtech.com/show/1668/10).

Comment: Hmm, the button sequence does not tell me the firmware version. If I do that without the cabel it just goes to the "screensaver/no signal"m mode. If I do that with the cable in it tells me "in power save mode" when I press the '-' button.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this kind of problems are coming from not correct grounding (or having different grounds).

I just took a cable and connect the chassis of my laptop to the chassis of my monitor, and it started to work.